# createUrl adding p=actions

Tags: craft3

Writing a plugin and creating some links. Trying to use:

```
$url = craft::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['', 'state' => 'KS']);
```

to create a URL. I am expecting:

> http://test.com/index.php?state=KS

but get:

> http://test.com/index.php?p=actions&state=KS

That results in the following error:

> HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
>   Template not found: actions

What is the p=actions that is being added to the url? I am a bit confused by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`craft::$app->urlManager->createUrl` will always return an action url because in the end this function does `return UrlHelper::actionUrl($route, $params);`

You want to create a basic site url so you need to do

```
UrlHelper::url('', ['state' => 'KR'] )
```